# Marker on map not appearing - react

Tags: reactjs

**Can someone tell me why my marker is not appearing on my map? The map is showing but the market is missing on the map.
Can someone please have a look?**

import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './About.css'
import {Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker} from 'google-maps-react';

class About extends React.Component {
    render() {

```
    const mapStyles = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
        };

    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
            <h1>About this app</h1>

            <div className="containerabout">
                <section className="aboutcreator">
                    <h2>About the creator</h2>
                    <img className="leftbox" src="/images/charles.jpg" style={{width:230}} alt="picturecharles"/>
                    <ul className="rightbox">
                        <li>26-year old, Belgian national</li>
                        <li>Full-stack JavaScript developer (MERN stack)</li>
                        <li>Background in M&A investment banking</li>
                        <li>Fluent in Dutch, French and English</li>
                        <li>Interests: Football, Cycling, Tennis, Venture Capital</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

                <section className="locationmap">
                    <h2>Ironhack Amsterdam campus</h2>

                    <Map
                        google={this.props.google}
                        zoom={14}
                        style={mapStyles}
                        initialCenter={{
                                lat: 52.370962,
                                lng: 4.883245
                            }}
                    />

                    <Marker position={{ lat:52.370962, lng:4.883245}}/>

                </section>
            </div>
        </DefaultLayout>
    )
}
```

}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDoNLDrCsLyfbQ7neWyxu_NogjdQ1GNTjM"
  })(About);

Answer (score 0):

Your marker needs to be inside your Map tag.

```
                <Map
                    google={this.props.google}
                    zoom={14}
                    style={mapStyles}
                    initialCenter={{
                            lat: 52.370962,
                            lng: 4.883245
                        }}
                >
                    <Marker position={{ lat:52.370962, lng:4.883245}}/>
                </Map>
```